# How to connect form submit NextJS to MongoDB?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js

I'm learning NextJS and can't figure out what solutions I need to link form and database? What hooks are better to use together with next for this task?

Data is added through Postman, but I don’t understand how to connect with the form

**My model**

```
import { model, models, Schema } from "mongoose";

const productModel = new Schema({
  id: Number,
  wallet: String,
  cover: String,
  title: String,
  description: String,
  url: String,
  price: String,
});

const Products = models.Products || model("Products", productModel);

export default Products;
```

**My connection**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const connectMongo = async () => {
  try {
    const { connection } = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);

    if (connection.readyState === 1) {
      console.log("MongoDB is connected");
    }
  } catch (errors) {
    return Promise.reject(errors);
  }
};

export default connectMongo;
```

**My controller**

```
import Products from "../models/productModel";

//POST .../api/product
async function postProduct(req, res) {
  try {
    const formData = req.body;
    if (!formData)
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "Form data isn't provided" });
    Products.create(formData, function (err, data) {
      return res.status(200).json(data);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(404).json({ error: "Error while post product" });
  }
}

export {postProduct}
```

**My helper**

```
const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:3000";

//Add new product
export async function postProduct(formData) {
  try {
    const Options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    };

    const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/api/products`, Options);
    const json = response.json();

    return json;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
}
```

**My API**

```
import connectMongo from "../../../database/connection/connectMongo";
import {
  deleteProduct,
  getProducts,
  postProduct,
  putProduct,
} from "../../../database/controllers";

export default function handler(req, res) {
  connectMongo().catch(() =>
    res.status(405).json({ error: "Connection error" })
  );

  //type of request
  const { method } = req;

  switch (method) {
    case "GET":
      getProducts(req, res);
      break;
    case "POST":
      postProduct(req, res);
      break;
    case "PUT":
      putProduct(req, res);
      break;
    case "DELETE":
      deleteProduct(req, res);
      break;
    default:
      res.setHeader("Allow", ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]);
      res.status(405).end(`Method ${method} not allowed `);
      break;
  }
}
```

**My Form**

```
import NewProductTabs from "./NewProductTabs";
import React from "react";
import { editProduct, postProduct } from "../../../database/helpers/helpers";

export default function NewProductForm() {
  return (
    <div className="flex-col gap-4">
      <NewProductTabs />
      <form
        onSubmit={postProduct}
        action="/api/form"
        method="post"
        className="flex flex-col gap-3 border border-black p-6 pb-10"
      >
        <div className="input-type gap-2">
          <label className="flex px-5 py-2 text-sm font-semibold">
            Cover image
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="image"
            className="w-full rounded-md border border-black px-5 py-5 text-sm shadow-brutal-sm focus:outline-none"
            placeholder="Image link"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="input-type gap-2">
          <label className="flex px-5 py-2 text-sm font-semibold">Title</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="title"
            className="w-full rounded-md border border-black px-5 py-5 text-sm shadow-brutal-sm focus:outline-none"
            placeholder="Title"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="input-type">
          <label className="flex px-5 py-2 text-sm font-semibold">
            About Product
          </label>
          <textarea
            rows="6"
            name="description"
            className="w-full rounded-md border border-black px-5 py-5 text-sm shadow-brutal-sm focus:outline-none"
            placeholder="Description"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="input-type">
          <label className="flex px-5 py-2 text-sm font-semibold">Url</label>
          <input
            type="url"
            name="url"
            className="w-full rounded-md border border-black px-5 py-5 text-sm shadow-brutal-sm focus:outline-none"
            placeholder="/url"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="input-type">
          <label className="flex px-5 py-2 text-sm font-semibold">Price</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="price"
            className="w-full rounded-md border border-black px-5 py-5 text-sm shadow-brutal-sm focus:outline-none"
            placeholder="Price, USDT"
          />
        </div>
      </form>
      <footer className="flex h-20">
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="flex w-full place-content-center bg-black p-2 text-sm font-bold"
        >
          <span className="flex items-center text-center text-white">
            {" "}
            Add product{" "}
          </span>
        </button>
      </footer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've watched videos, read articles, but haven't figured out what needs to be done yet.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several issues here, I would suggest console.log errors from your fetch call (instead of just returning) on the frontend to help narrow things down.

First thing I notice is inconsistencies with your API route:

- In your controller, you list `/api/product` as the route
- Your helper function you are posting to `/api/products` (note the **'s'** on the end)
- The form component uses `/api/form` as the action route. You should not have a method or action in this case because your `onSubmit()` method is already handling the logic. If you do wish to use native form methods, ensure that your routes are correct.

The other big thing I notice is that you do not have values assigned to any of your inputs. It is preferable to create "controlled components" in React to track input value changes in the DOM. See these [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).

A basic example might look like this in your case:

```js
class NewProductForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { imageValue: '', titleValue: '', descriptionValue: '' };

    this.handleTitleChange = this.handleTitleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleTitleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ titleValue: event.target.value });
  }

  async handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const response = await postProduct(this.state)
    console.log(response)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div className="...">
          <label className="...">Title</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="title"
            className="..."
            placeholder="Title"
            value={this.state.titleValue}
            onChange={this.handleTitleChange}
          />
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, the API address is correct (/products). The error is only in the comment.

I don’t understand then, I import the postProduct, point it to onSubmit, but nothing happens when I click.

If you write like this, and add to inputs
   // function handleSubmit(event) {
   // postProduct();
   // }

Then empty fields come to the database

I tried to rewrite your example on a functional component, apparently I made a mistake somewhere, it didn’t work